# Java app key shortcut

Tags: java, shortcut

So I have a JDialog with a focus listener that, when the frame is not focused anymore, it hides it. Can I make a key combination that when pressed, to make the frame visible again?

I thought about using the key listener but I suppose the  listener works only when the object to whom I added it is focused, so it would be useless in my case.

Comment: Do I get you right - no component of your application has focus and *then* you want to focus on your frame through a key combination? Something similiar to ALT+TAB on Windows?

Comment: Yes, something like that.. but to make the frame visible also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could take a look at:

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

Comment: the key listener works only when the object to whom I add the listener is focused, so here I can't use it